# Mix OpenCL with OpenGL

Tags: linux, opengl, opencl

Is it ok to use both OpenGL an OpenCL in one program? Both operate on GPU and I'm afraid how switching between OpenCL and OpenGL is handled in "background" (e.g. registers are overwritten).

I'm using Linux working on computer with some nVidia graphic 8k, so i can use OpenCL implemented on top of the CUDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"is it ok to use both OpenGL an OpenCL in one program? Both operate on GPU and I'm afraid how switching between OpenCL and OpenGL is handled in "background"

Not to worry much about that , you can create a context which will be shared by both the API's , You can also create OpenCL buffer from OpenGL buffer hence there is not overhead in data transfer between API's . please continue with the work also inform us what was the advantage of interoperability. Calculation will be done by kernel rendering will be done by OpenGL.

I am providing some liks which might be helpful for you.

http://www.dyn-lab.com/articles/cl-gl.html

http://enja.org/2010/08/27/adventures-in-opencl-part-2-particles-with-opengl/

http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=99&Itemid=150

http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=140&Itemid=199

[OpenCL research/ academic papers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550006/opencl-research-academic-papers)

http://rastergrid.com/blog/category/programming/graphics/

http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=245351

Best Regards
Megharaj.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine, you can even share data between OpenCL and OpenGL.

Comment: Where can read about details about sharing data between both solutions?

Comment: See the appendix of the CL specification about creating CL buffers from GL buffersn and take a look at the CL_KHR_gl_sharing extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

OpenCL 1.1 includes significant new functionality including::

*Improved OpenGL **interoperability** through efficient sharing of images and buffers by linking OpenCL event objects to OpenGL fence sync objects*

http://www.khronos.org/opencl/

Comment: One thing to note (and actually something i tripped over) is that you have to get the OpenCL context from your OpenGL context ... else object sharing won't work.

Comment: @Florian: Most important comment! (...and, also, most annoying feature of CL/GL interop).