# OpenCL research/ academic papers

Tags: opencl

I'm about to start my honours project at uni on OpenCL and how it can be used to improve modern game development. I know there is a couple of books out now/soon about learning opencl but I was wondering if anyone knows any good papers on opencl.

I've been looking but can't seem to find any. Part of my project requires a literary review and contrast so any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as resource rec.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll not point you directly to any papers, instead I'll give you a few hints on where to look for them.

1. [Google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/), One of the best places on the web to search for papers on any subject. Searching for "opencl game development" turned up a few interesting results right on the first page; for sure there are other valuable results in the following pages.
2. [IEEE Explore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/guesthome.jsp?reload=true); IEEE is one of the *de facto* establishments on all thing computer and electronics; their journals and conferences have many publications on OpenCL in particular and parallel processing in general. IEEE Explore is their search engine, although usually all articles are also referenced in Google Scholar (but may be easier to find using IEEE explore).
3. [ACM Digital Libray](http://portal.acm.org/); ACM is a large and important institution like IEEE, but with even bigger focus on computing. You will find many papers on OpenCL there.
4. Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc; sometimes when everything else fails, using normal search engines can go a long way. You may find information about ongoing projects, important game developers blog posts, etc. All of these can be valid references if there aren't more (be sure to search really well before concluding there aren't more).

You should favor articles published in scientific journals over: a) papers or extended abstracts published in conference proceedings; b) corporate articles, not peer-reviewed, usually found in the respective corporation websites; c) articles published in general scientific knowledge magazines (e.g. Scientific American, etc.).

Sometimes you may not be given access to certain papers, which you will be requested to purchase. Usually, universities have subscriptions to many journals or such, as such you may have better luck trying to download the PDFs when accessing the web inside your institution. If you have no luck, sometimes the authors put "preview/unfinished" copies of the articles in their websites (sometimes they even put the dubiously legal published copy). As a last resort, you can always contact the authors directly, they'll most likely send you the article by email (it's of their own interest).

Finally, to learn OpenCL, I found that a mixture of [reference manual](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.1.pdf), [quick reference card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-quick-reference-card.pdf) and looking at examples from [Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-sdk/), [AMD](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/Pages/default.aspx), [Nvidia](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40) and [IBM](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/opencl/download) SDK's goes a long way. No doubt a book will help, though I can't recommend you any, because I didn't read any.

This probably isn't the answer you wanted, but believe me, it's the answer you need to do a good work.

Good luck!

Comment: In computer graphics, the best papers are published in Siggraph, which is a conference. It is also a special issue of a journal indeed, but still.

Comment: Hi Korchkidu, OpenCL is not specific for computer graphics (although it supports operations on images), nonetheless articles from Siggraph conference are available at the ACM Digital Library (Siggraph is part of ACM), which I refer in my answer. Best regards.

Comment: My comment was just about your statement "You should favor articles published in scientific journals". Just to say it is not true in all fields.